# Joining row with column in its own table

Tags: sql

I have a table generated after inner join which is like

Table after join.

```
ID_ACC | Model_1 | Model_2 | Model_3 | ACTUAl |  
  1    | m1_val1 | m2_val1 | m3_val1 |  val1  |  
  2    | m1_val2 | m2_val2 | m3_val2 |  val2  |  
  3    | m1_val3 | m2_val3 | m3_val3 |  val3  |  
  4    | m1_val4 | m2_val4 | m3_val4 |  val4  |  
  5    | m1_val5 | m2_val5 | m3_val5 |  val5  |
```

I want this table to updated and make new table which should be like this

Table that is required.

```
ID_ACC | Model   | Value   | ACTUAl |  
  1    | Model_1 | m1_val1 |  val1  |  
  1    | Model_2 | m1_val2 |  val1  |  
  1    | Model_3 | m1_val3 |  val1  |  
  2    | Model_1 | m2_val1 |  val2  |  
  2    | Model_2 | m2_val2 |  val2  |  
  2    | Model_3 | m2_val3 |  val2  |  
  3    | Model_1 | m3_val1 |  val3  |  
  3    | Model_2 | m3_val2 |  val3  |  
  3    | Model_3 | m3_val3 |  val3  |  
  4    | Model_1 | m4_val1 |  val4  |  
  4    | Model_2 | m4_val2 |  val4  |  
  4    | Model_3 | m4_val3 |  val4  |  
  5    | Model_1 | m5_val1 |  val5  |  
  5    | Model_2 | m5_val2 |  val5  |  
  5    | Model_3 | m5_val3 |  val5  |
```

So what should be the query to get this results from the above table?

Comment: Can you add you original table in this question? Points are not clear.

Comment: I have removed those conflicting dbms tags. Put one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Comment: If that is the result of an inner join, maybe it's better to change that query to not join multiple rows into columns to start with.

Comment: Thank you but the solution that is provided below is working properly for me and the reason for not adding the original data is that the data consist of sensitive data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use union all

```
select ID_ACC, 'Model_1' as model,Model_1 as value, actual from tablename
union all
select ID_ACC, 'Model_2' as model,Model_2 as value, actual from tablename
union all
select ID_ACC, 'Model_3' as model,Model_3 as value, actual from tablename
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution this is what I was looking for and got to know about the union all more better.

Answer (score 0):

The following is standard ANSI SQL:

```
select t.*
from models
  cross join lateral ( 
     values  
         (id_acc, model_1, 'Model 1', actual),
         (id_acc, model_2, 'Model 2', actual),
         (id_acc, model_3, 'Model 3', actual)
  ) as t(id_acc, value, model, actual)
order by id_acc;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/ZHZJR43210

---

Or using the `UNPIVOT` operator:

```
select id_acc, model, value, actual
from models
  unpivot (value for model in (model_1 as 'Model 1', 
                               model_2 as 'Model 2', 
                               model_3 as 'Model 3'));
```

Online example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e270ddae4449127a64a345f0066832e6